# python elasticsearch elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056))

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect to an elasticsearch server using the elasticsearch package, but getting this error

```
  File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-J1KVvbjz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 152, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-J1KVvbjz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 331, in exists
    "HEAD", _make_path(index), params=params, headers=headers
  File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-J1KVvbjz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 390, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-J1KVvbjz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 365, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-J1KVvbjz/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 255, in perform_request
    raise SSLError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056))
```

Any ideas what could be fixing the problem ?

Comment: In my case, I just changed all https to http in my project code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your's openssl version

run

```
openssl version
```

or from python

```
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

Both commands need to output something like: **LibreSSL 2.8.3**

For connecting with this client you probably use something like in their docs:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/#ssl-and-authentication

and as you can see at the comment bellow the example
you can set some of your own settings on **Urllib3HttpConnection**

```
See class Urllib3HttpConnection for detailed description of the options.
```

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/connection.html#elasticsearch.Urllib3HttpConnection

There you will see the setting of ssl version

**ssl_version – version of the SSL protocol to use. Choices are: SSLv23 (default) SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 (see PROTOCOL_ constants in the ssl module for exact**

Try to change this setting and see if it help.